# LintError Unknown issue id "StyleCycle"

Tags: android-studio

Updated to gradle 4.6 using android studio 3.2 beta 4 and now I get the following error when running `lintProdRelease`

`Unknown issue id "StyleCycle", found in ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom `lint.xml` file, delete the following line:

`<issue id="StyleCycle" ...`

Comment: Not using a custom file, turns out I had to revert and wait for full release and all worked smooth afterwords.